# Parse missing element

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to parse some info from html by using python bs4

```
<div class="section">
        <a class="site" href="www.example1.com">Site1</a>                   
</div>
<div class="section">
        <a class="bogus" href="www.idontneed1.com">Idontneedthis1</a>               
</div>
<div class="section">
        <a class="site" href="www.example2.com">Site2</a>                   
</div>
<div class="section">
        <a class="site" href="www.example3.com">Site3</a>                   
</div>
<div class="section">
        <a class="bogus" href="www.idontneed2.com">Idontneedthis2</a>                   
</div>
```

I want to parse those hrefs into a list like this:

```
[{"site":"www.example1.com"}, {"site":" "}, {"site":"www.example2.com"}, {"site":"www.example3.com"}, {"site":" "}]
```

Instead I have this:

```
[{"site":"www.example1.com"}, {"site":"www.example2.com"}, {"site":"www.example3.com"}]
```

I already have a filter to exclude "bogus" but I need a code that says if "section" do not have a "site" then leave " ".

Keep in mind it is just an example -- I need a versatile solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension where you will test if the specific class is present. For example:

```py
out = [
    {"site": " " if "bogus" in a["class"] else a["href"]}
    for a in soup.select(".section > a")
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"site": "www.example1.com"},
    {"site": " "},
    {"site": "www.example2.com"},
    {"site": "www.example3.com"},
    {"site": " "},
]
```

Comment: May change the statment to `if "site" not in a["class"] else a["href"]` cause it seems to fit the following better: *I need a code that says if "section" do not have a "site" then leave " "*